# Nothing is shown in a tag

Tags: python, django

Nothing is shown in a tag.
I wrote in views.py

```
def top(request):
    content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
    category_content = Category.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]

    return render(request, 'top.html',{'content':content,'category_content':category_content})
```

in models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

in top.html

```
<ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item active text-center">category</li>
               <div class="collapse">
                     {% for category in category_content %}
                        <a href="" class="list-group-item">
                        {{ category.name }}
                        </a>
                     {% endfor %}
               </div>
</ul>
```

Now output is like
[image: current outout]

so category.name  is not shown.My ideal output is
[image: ideal output]

I really cannot understand why category.name is not shown.I print out `print(category_content)` in views.py's top method,so , ]> is shown.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: Where does `POST` comes from? `content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Categories are not visible, because you used `collapse` CSS class in the div, which means it's not displayed.

If you check Bootstrap 4 documentation on [collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/), you'll see that it states

> .collapse hides content